# Get Filtered List of users using Forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using forms authentication and need to get a list of users that have a certain role and have a certain value in a certain profile property.  The way I am doing this is to call Membership.GetAllUsers and then looping through them and checking the roles and profile.  Is there a better way to do this in 1 call so that I don't have to get all users back and iterate?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `GetUsersInRole()` method.

```
string []users=System.Web.Security.Roles.GetUsersInRole("role");
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to replace `Membership.GetAllUsers` with `Roles.GetUsersInRole(string roleName)` - at least you'll have less entries to check for your custom field value.